# Need help with ncurses cursor and threads

Tags: cursor, pthreads, mutex, ncurses

I am using ncurses to write a text-based client in C. The main loop of the program simply blocks until a keypress is detected and then handles it and continues to wait for another keypress.

I have a single thread I launch (posted below) that blocks (using select) waiting for input from the server and when it receives it adds it to the chat log buffer and prints the buffer to the screen. It works perfectly.

I know ncurses is not thread safe but my understanding of threads is that as long as I make 100% sure that only one thread is making calls to ncurses at a time, it will work fine.

My issue is with the cursor position.

It is modified with the line `move(height+1, curx);`
 and no matter what values I pass to it, ncurses seems to ignore the call entirely and places my cursor at a different position. I cannot seem to influence it.

To further explain the problem, in my main thread (the keypress loop), I use the same mutex blocking. When the cursor is updated in those sections of code, it works as planned. When it is updated from the receive thread below, the cursor call is ignored.

Any ideas?

`receive thread`

```
   char buf[512];

    fd_set read_fds;
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);

    int nbytes;

    for (;;) {

            read_fds = master;
            select(sockfd+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexdisplay);

            memset(&buf, 0, sizeof buf);
            nbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, 512, 0);
            buf[nbytes] = 0;

            add_chatmsg(chatlog, &numchatlog, buf);

            // erase window
            werase(chat_window);

            // redraw border
            wborder(chat_window, '|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+');

            // scroll completely into the future
            chatlogstart = numchatlog-1;

            // print the chat log
            print_chatlog(chatlog, &numchatlog, &chatlogstart, &height);

            move(height+1, curx);

            // refresh window
            wrefresh(chat_box);
            wrefresh(chat_window);

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexdisplay);

    }
```

Comment: Why use a thread when you use select? don't over-complicate things!

Comment: you are right and wrong. select blocks which would prevent the UI from working while it checks for data. At least during my tests.

However, I was over complicating things and ended up fixing the issue

Answer (score 0):

May be its too late for an answer to this question.

You didnt specify on which window you want to control the cursor. I am assuming that you wanted the cursor at the (height+1, curx) position of the  chat_box or chat_window.

One can control the cursor with move funtion in the stdout widow which is the original terminal but not on the windows(chat_box and chat_window) you created. The function for for controlling the cursor in user created windows is wmove.

int move(int y, int x);

int wmove(WINDOW *win, int y, int x);

Hope this helps others facing similar problem. Please do point if this is not the correct solution.